# Unable to set JAVA_HOME in IntelliJ using H2 database

Tags: java, h2, java-home

I created a project with the H2 database source code. I am trying to build the code but it keeps saying JAVA_HOME is not set so it won't build. However I set the JDK path in the project structure seen here.
[image: Picture of set JDK path]

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.
Btw, the screenshot is not very helpful as is.

Comment: Hey can you include the picture how you setup JAVA_HOME variable in system environment variables?

Comment: @rileyw, Please follow [these](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/) instructions. Also, no need to rename your Java installation directory for that.